# Aggregate data to quarter-level retaining indicator variables and fit linear model in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, linear-regression

My data is structured such that, for each `quarter`, I have a binary outcomes `y` for each entity. Entities are identified by unique `id` values. Each `id` also has two dummy variables, `d1` and `d2`, that indicate some characteristic about the entity. Example data given below:

```
dat <- data.frame(rep(c(1, 2, 3), 4), c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1), c(rep('Q1', 3), rep('Q2', 3), rep('Q3', 3), rep('Q4', 3)), rep(c(1,0,1), 4), rep(c(1,1,0),4))
colnames(dat) <- c('id', 'y', 'quarter', 'd1', 'd2')
```

I would like to (1) aggregate this data to the `quarter`-level, proportion of entities with `y` equal to 1 in a given `quarter`, and (2) understand how `d1` and `d1` affect this proportion.

(1) I attempt to aggregate using dplyr as follows:

```
datq <- dat %>% group_by(quarter, d1, d2) %>% summarise(n_y = n_distinct(id[y == 1]), n = n_distinct(id)) %>% mutate(prop_y = n_y / n)
```

In order to retain my dummy variables, however, I end up with multiple quarterly observations. This introduces issues when (2) I attempt to examine difference in proportions by dummy variable.

With the above aggregated data, `datq`, I can fit the model:

```
lm_d1 <- lm(prop_y ~ d1, data = datq)
```

And similarly for `d2`. However, the parameter estimates, SE, etc. are different if I aggregate the original `dat` data by `d1` and `d2` separately, i.e. `group_by(quarter, d1)` or `group_by(quarter, d2` rather than what I have above - `group_by(quarter, d1, d2)`.

Would someone be able to tell me (1) if/how I am aggregating this data incorrectly and (2) explain how these different data structures are affecting my fitted models and their interpretations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the non-aggregated variables, there is no need to use `summarize`. Once you group by the desired grouping variable, all calculations you do are carried out within those groups. So simply using `mutate` will suffice.

```
datq <- dat %>% 
  group_by(quarter) %>% 
  mutate(prop_y = sum(y) / n()) # n() gets the number of observations within each group
datq

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   quarter [4]
      id     y quarter    d1    d2 prop_y
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  1.00  1.00 Q1       1.00  1.00  0.667
 2  2.00  1.00 Q1       0     1.00  0.667
 3  3.00  0    Q1       1.00  0     0.667
 4  1.00  0    Q2       1.00  1.00  0.333
 5  2.00  1.00 Q2       0     1.00  0.333
 6  3.00  0    Q2       1.00  0     0.333
 7  1.00  0    Q3       1.00  1.00  0.333
 8  2.00  0    Q3       0     1.00  0.333
 9  3.00  1.00 Q3       1.00  0     0.333
10  1.00  1.00 Q4       1.00  1.00  1.00 
11  2.00  1.00 Q4       0     1.00  1.00 
12  3.00  1.00 Q4       1.00  0     1.00
```

Now as far the modeling you are doing, your SEs different because the number of observations differ. N is used to compute SEs, so if they differ, the SEs will differ. But this won't necessarily impact the point estimates.

```
> datq <- dat %>% 
+   group_by(quarter, d1, d2) %>% 
+   summarise(n_y = n_distinct(id[y == 1]), n = n_distinct(id)) %>% 
+   mutate(prop_y = n_y / n)
> nrow(datq)
[1] 12
> summary(lm(prop_y ~ d1, data = datq))

Call:
lm(formula = prop_y ~ d1, data = datq)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -0.75  -0.50   0.25   0.50   0.50 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.7500     0.2622   2.860   0.0169 *
d1           -0.2500     0.3211  -0.778   0.4543  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5244 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05714,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.03714 
F-statistic: 0.6061 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.4543

> 
> datq2 <- dat %>% 
+   group_by(quarter, d1) %>% 
+   summarise(n_y = n_distinct(id[y == 1]), n = n_distinct(id)) %>% 
+   mutate(prop_y = n_y / n)
> nrow(datq2)
[1] 8
> summary(lm(prop_y ~ d1, data = datq2))

Call:
lm(formula = prop_y ~ d1, data = datq2)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-0.750 -0.125  0.125  0.250  0.500 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.7500     0.2282   3.286   0.0167 *
d1           -0.2500     0.3227  -0.775   0.4680  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4564 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.09091,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.06061 
F-statistic:   0.6 on 1 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.468
```

Comment: Thanks for your note! This is really helpful. It isn't recreated in my above version, but my point estimates do differ in my actual data. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Point estimates will change if the data change, so I would guess that in the different aggregations you are doing, the data differ. It's a weird coincidence that they match in this case.